# Myriad Pro : Font shape `OT1/MyriadPro-OsF/m/n' undefined

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex, adobe

I am trying to install MyriadPro on my MiKTeX 2.9 (32bit). Sadly, something, somewhere seems to have gone wrong. I allready installed MinionPro on my TeX Distribution and basically I proceeded the same way installing MyriadPro. The font files have been taken from my Adobe Reader 11 installation, I then used LCDF typetools to create .otf font files and placed them in my local texmf folder

> C:\Users\Friedrich\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\

aswell as in my MikTeX path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\

The other needed date has been taken from

> http://www.gaehrken.de/fonts/

and I used the manual from github

> https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub

Finally I edited the updmap.cfg in my MiKTeX 2.9 path with

> %Myriad Pro
>
> Map MyriadPro.map

and did run

> texhash
>
> initexmf -u
>
> updmap

Everything went fine so far, I also checked if the Map was found (and it was). But when I try compiling a test document using pdfLaTeX, TeXMaker gives me

> Font shape `OT1/MyriadPro-OsF/m/n' undefined(Font) using`OT1/cmr/m/n' instead
>
> Some font shapes where not available, defaults substituted.

My minimal working example would be this

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=false, twoside=false, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[default]{MyriadPro}

\begin{document}

This is some test text. iPod should look like the original Apple Font.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` before loading `MyriadPro` help? (Although OT1 would work for me.)

Comment: What is in `tex/latex/MyriadPro/`? On my system, I have `ot1myriad-osf.fd` and NOT `OT1MyriadPro-OsF.fd` but this likely varies depending on version. And the file seems to define `OT1Myriad-OsF`.

Comment: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} did the job, thank you very much. 
All the font names inside that folder start with T, mostly T1, some of them are TS1 aswell. No clue what the matter is with that.

Comment: `TS1` is the supplementary text encoding. If you use the `textcomp` package, it provides additional text symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the particular version you have, the `MyriadPro` package may not provide the `OT1` font encoding. To use the `T1` encoding instead (which is recommended in any case), add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

before loading `MyriadPro`.
To make use of the additional text symbols in the `TS1` supplementary encoding, add

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

as well.